# Why does FB.getLoginStatus() return noSuchMethod error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement a Facebook login on my website using the [Facebook javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript). Following [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3) I set up the basis like this:

```
// Loads the FB sdk asynchronously
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxx',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.2'
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

After which I try to invoke the `FB.getLoginStatus()` method like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#fb-login').click(function(){
        console.log('clicked my login button');
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
});
```

But unfortunately my console only says this:

```
"clicked my login button"
Error: __noSuchMethod__ is deprecated
```

Does anybody know what is wrong and how I can fix this? All tips are welcome!

Comment: looks like a bug. but why would you use getLoginStatus on click? FB.login is what you need.

Comment: @luschn - But as far as I know I first need to check the loginstatus before I can need to login. But as you suggestion I tried the login() method as well (`FB.login(function(response) {console.log(response);});`), which results in the same `Error: __noSuchMethod__ is deprecated`. Any ideas?

Comment: getLoginStatus should be used on page load, not on click: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: @luschn - In the official example by Facebook they do it on click: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.4

Comment: i know, that official example is very bad. don´t just copy examples, make sure you understand what´s happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is humiliating to say this, but it turned out that my [browser plugin ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com/) blocked loading of the Facebook SDK. After turning it off, it worked like a charm.

I hope this answer helps other people running into this stupidity to fix it a bit faster than I did.. :)

I wish you all a beautiful day!

Answer (score -1):

You're getting this error because the API version used by your app is deprecated and therefore the errors are no longer fixed.

Pass the latest version `v2.4` or `v2.3`.